# Export Data From Dategridview to XML file using C#

Tags: c#, xml, datagrid

I've searched the web, looke at the top 3 pages of results in Google (which seemed to be going the other way, IE populating a datagrive view from an xml file) and searched for a youtube video.

What is the code you'd use to export results from a `datagridview` to an `xml` file? Please bare in mind I'm very new to this and so I have no idea how to do it and all the results I've found don't give me any more of an idea.

If it helps I'm using visual studio.

Comment: You shouldn't. Export from the data (`List<>` or DataTable) that the GridView binds to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get table from gridview and then you can use **WriteXml** method of datatable.

For Example your gridview name is dgvMyMembers

To get datatable from gridview refer following code.

```
DataTable dst = new DataTable();
dst = (DataTable)dgvMyMembers.DataSource;
dst.TableName = "DataGridviewTpXml";
dst.WriteXml(@"Filepath", true);
```

where Filepath like c:\users\name\desktop\myxml.xml

Another Example with datatable.

```
DataTable dst = new DataTable();
dst.Columns.Add("no", typeof(int));
dst.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
DataRow row = dst.NewRow();
row[0] = 1;
row[1] = "name1";

DataRow row1 = dst.NewRow();
row1[0] = 2;
row1[1] = "name2";
dst.Rows.Add(row);
dst.Rows.Add(row1);
dst.TableName = "DataGridviewTpXml";
dst.WriteXml(@"C:\Users\prabu\Desktop\myxml.xml", true);
```

You will get output like the following code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>
    <DocumentElement>
       <DataGridviewTpXml>
          <no>1</no>
          <name>name1</name>
       </DataGridviewTpXml>
       <DataGridviewTpXml>
          <no>2</no>
          <name>name2</name>
       </DataGridviewTpXml>
    </DocumentElement>
```

The WriteXml method provides a way to write either data only, or both data and schema from a DataTable into an XML document, whereas the WriteXmlSchema method writes only the schema. To write both data and schema, use one of the overloads that includes the XmlWriteMode parameter, and set its value to WriteSchema.[**For more info**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3zy2whb.aspx)

Comment: Please add a summary to avoid link-only-answers or post a comment.

Comment: Can you give me more detail? i really do not know what I'm doing?

Comment: @GeorgeIanGuyMarsden Are you tried my code ,its working or not .let me know